# What's the best practice for an "n/a" result when it would normally be a boolean value?

Tags: json, api, http, https, microservices

I'm working on an api that provides JSON responses. One of the items is typically a bool, but in some cases, it is "n/a".

The two options I'm considering are:

1. Returning a string like "N/A"
2. Returning a value of null

The first option is "truthy" though and if someone implemented the API poorly, it could result in a false positive (although it's a little more clear to a human reader). The second result is "falsey" but doesn't really provide the same clarity to a human reader of the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with `null` which means that property does not have any value, regardless if it's boolean, string etc. It will keep data type consistent, otherwise you would have to mix `Boolean` with `String` which is probably bad idea and will definitely not make life of API consumers easier. Or keep the value string and pass `Boolean` as a `String`, which also sounds like a workaround.

`N/A` seems to be more like a representation of `null` value on the consumer side. And by the way different consumers can represent it in different way. Or it could be not the same for different locales.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was leaning towards, as I like not mixing the type.